# File changed through Github disappears after commit from another developer

Tags: git, github

So I wanted to make some quick changes to the README.md file on a private Github repo for a work project. Wanting to be quick, I decided to perform them through Github's web editor. I made the changes and then committed and everything looked good.

My co-worker was notified of the changes via a Slack update. He had some local changes in the same repository and soon pushed his changes to GH. However, he forget to do a pull first, but he was never stopped by git for his local being out of date. We check back in GH and my changes to the readme file are gone. I have no record in the commit history on the master branch. My co-worker's changes do not show any modifications to the readme file.

I happen to have a link to the commit provided by the Slack update and that still works. It shows my changes to the readme file, so GH is aware of what I did. Where those changes went though I have no idea.

1.) Why was my co-worker's push allowed to proceed? He did NOT add the `--force` flag so I'm baffled as to why it even went through.

2.) Where does my commit exist at this point and why did it disappear?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a link to the repository and commit in question?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it is a private repo owned by my employer.

Comment: Is your commit included in the list of commits on `master`? On some other branch? Does your colleague's commit include your commit as a parent? Does the diff view for your colleague's commit show any changes to `README.md`?

Comment: Use the link you have to view your commit. In the header area, below the commit message, it should list any branches that contain the commit. What do you see there? Below that, to the right of the committer info, it should list any parent(s) that the commit has. What do you see there?

Comment: The branch label is simply missing. The parent listed is an actual commit to master.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75979/discussion-between-chris-and-xhr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub support says that the push from my co-worker was using "force" and that is why my changes were lost. My co-worker was not even aware of said flag though. While it may still be an issue with GH, I see no value in pursuing this further provided it does not reoccur.